# Unable to get Facebook Publish Permission - Android

Tags: android, facebook, publish

I am trying to get the publish_actions permission from the user for my app. The user has already logged in through facebook and in that instance I asked for some read permissions that the app needs. Getting the read permissions worked fine but there seems to be some problem with publish_actions. My code is:

```
private void asktopublish() {
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
    CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {

                }
            });
}
```

When the user clicks the button on my to grant the permission, the Facebook activity opens but closes almost instantly and seems to be empty as well.

I've tried looking for other solutions online but they all use the older fb sdk.

Comment: Is the user you are using for the tests added as a developer/admin/tester on the developers.facebook.com app?

Comment: @MBat No, but I have made the app public so that should not be a problem right? The read permissions work fine

Comment: The permission `publish_actions` requires review by Facebook, before that only the developers/testers/admins can use it, try to add it as one of those roles and see if it works :)

Comment: Added the user worked. Thanks!

Comment: @MBat Any idea when can the users who are not added as developers/testers can grant publish permissions. How long does the review by fb take?

Comment: The other users can only use it after Facebook approves it.
After the review they will be able to use it :)

The review normally takes 1 or 2 days

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @MBat suggested, I added the user as a tester and it works

Comment: you just made my day